# MongoDB - How to hide a certain value from the results?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following aggregate query which for some of the results, I have a null value. I want to update this query so it hides the null values from the result(not removes those documents)

How would I update this query to hide the null values?

[image]

```
  {
        "$addFields": {
            "otherTexts": {
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$otherTextsArray",
                    "initialValue": "",
                    "in": {
                        "$concat": [
                            "$$value",
                            {
                                "$cond": [
                                    { "$eq": ["$$value", ""] },
                                    "",
                                    ", "
                                ]
                            },
                            "$$this"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "TestingFeatures": {
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$AppFeatures",
                    "initialValue": "",
                    "in": {
                        "$concat": [
                            "$$value",
                            {
                                "$cond": [
                                    { "$eq": ["$$value", ""] },
                                    "",
                                    ", "
                                ]
                            },
                            "$$this"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "otherTextsArray": 0
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some example documents in JSON format.